# How can I probe file open and close at VFS using SystemTap

Tags: linux, vfs, systemtap

I seen example of SystemTap script using `probe syscall.open.return { }` 
But there are some application doesn't call systemcall 
So how can I probe file open at VFS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you want to probe vfs open operations, do:

```
# stap -L 'kernel.function("vfs_*")'
[...]
kernel.function("vfs_open@fs/open.c:862") $path:struct path const* $filp:struct file* $cred:struct cred const*
[...]

# stap -e 'probe kernel.function("vfs_open") { /* ... */ }'
```

where the `...` could include printing context variables, identification of the calling process, backtraces, `task_dentry_path(task_current(), $path->dentry, $path->mnt)`, etc.